# Single Joomla Article Appering as white page

Tags: php, html, joomla, content-management-system

I recently became administrator for several sites. I did not build these. One of these we will be making changes to but I noticed while reviewing content that one article (climate, under the visit deming tab) leads to a blank page.

I checked the article to ensure it has content. It does.

It has a flash slideshow (idk why flash but not my isssue), I removed that from the article in case it was having a weird interaction. still no good.

I clicked preview and the content shows up fine in the pop up.

I double checked the menu link to ensure that it had the right page, it does

I created a new article with a new menu link and still no good.

the site is cityofdeming.org

I did not build this site, and my background is mostly wordpress.

Lets get this figured out and you win the internet!

images of issue here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Q_28239030.html

Comment: just our of curiosity, what happens if you turn SEF off? Also are you getting any errors in the error log?

Comment: I get a 500 error when I visit the page.

Comment: Are you running Joomla 1.5? I just had a Joomla 1.5 site that had this happen for all articles on the site and it turned out that the site had been hacked with a file added at `/includes/joomla_rss.php` which was then being included within `/includes/application.php`. The include was prefaced with `@` so I assume it was generating a fatal error but the error was suppressed, so no record in the error log.

Comment: Tried it with SEF off, no change , I am waiting on a call back from our host for that site because I expected a 500, and looked for anything weird in application.php but saw nothing odd

Comment: YOu could try turning error reporting to maximum and see if there is something there. If the host upgraded php there are likely many warnings and notices at minimum and possibly an extension is using deprecated code from php 4.